# The word that means for eating at midnight

Tags: word-request

What are midnight snacks or meals called?
If you already ate three meals in the day, but you eat a fourth meal, what is it called?

Comment: I don't think there *is* another word. "Fourth meal" is used in some restaurant advertising, I know, and "midnight snack" is a pretty typical phrase in general. I think those are what such meals are called.

Comment: Midnight snacks are called *midnight snacks*.

Answer (score 12):

Given that my comment saying this got six up-votes, I'm getting the impression that people agree with me, so here it is as an answer.

As far as I know, there isn't another word.

"Fourth meal" is used in some restaurant advertising (I think that's what Taco Bell says, or had said in a past campaign), and "midnight snack" is a pretty typical phrase in general. I think those are what such meals are called. "Midnight snack" is definitely the more common of the two, for what that's worth.